# When a variable should be set as a private class variable (e.g. _var) vs a class constant (e.g. VAR) vs a private class constant (e.g. _VAR)?

Tags: python, coding-style

I'm finding myself unsure as to whether I should set certain variables that I use in my class as being private class variables (e.g. _var) vs class constant variables (e.g. VAR) vs a private class constant variable if such a thing is used (e.g. _VAR).  I realize that this doesn't really matter in Python aside from convention, but would like to know which way is right (or more right).

For instance, let's say I have a certain variable for storing the regex pattern for height.  Let's say I have no intention of modifying this anywhere in the class or elsewhere in the code, and in fact I only use it in one of the class methods, which should I go with then:

Option 1 - set as private class variable:

```
_height_pattern = r"""(#'##?"?)|#'"""
```

Option 2 - set as a constant class variable

```
HEIGHT_PATTERN = r"""(#'##?"?)|#'"""
```

Option 3 - set as a constant private class variable (not sure if such a thing exists or if I've ever seen a variable declaed in this for)

```
_HEIGHT_PATTERN = r"""(#'##?"?)|#'"""
```

Or perhaps some other option I haven't thought of.  Note that in this case I've picked a variable that I'd think people would be able to make a good case for one way or the other.  However, there are also other cases where I feel it'd be more vague.  For instance, what if I have a random-seed variable (_SEED=2000?) whose changing wouldn't have a fundamental impact on functionality?  Thus, if you can share some easy to follow rule of thumb, that'd be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1):

> and in fact I only use it in one of the class methods

Then there's no doubt this shouldn't be a class variable at all. I would declare it inside the method as a constant.

However, I understand that your question is a bit more broad than this single example you gave, so let's imagine that this variable you speak of would be used in more than one method. In this case, as I also have never seen anything like option 3 (and hell it is ugly), you should go with option 2, as it's more important that your code says that this variable is **not** to be modified than to tell that it should not be accessed outside its class.

Comment: What if the variable takes a tiny bit of time to compute - eg relies on str.maketrans, and while it's only used in 1 class method, that class method is called repeatedly many times (it's applied to every row in a large dataset), should I then stick to having it as a class variable to save the accumulated processing time?

Comment: Not sure if `str.maketrans` would be a good example since it might not be a good idea to apply `maketrans` to a value on script initialization, as its return might vary on each call (otherwise it wouldn't make sense to use it instead of using the final value I think). Nevertheless, if that's the case, I'd say that the final paragraph of my answer applies.

Answer (score 0):

According to [pep-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) constants should be all captialized and use underscore when needed. Example `HEIGHT_PATTERN`.

As a more general note coding "style" for python can be found in pep 8 (see link above)